# Extract pre-defined words from a compile-time constant string

Tags: c, gcc, c-preprocessor, compile-time

I have a configuration file that the user can modify.

In this configuration file there exists a `#define ListOfWords` with a list of words to which the user can add or remove any custom words. For example: `#define ListOfWords black,bear,Mouse`.

User then also defines, using `#define SequenceOfWords`, an arbitrary sequence of words. For example: `#define SequenceOfWords In a forest, a brown-bear saw a black mouse`.

I want to extract every word from `#define ListOfWords` that appears in `#SequenceOfWords` and create a compile-time string array of extracted words `const char* extractedWords[] = {bear, black}`.

*Note:* Instead of `#define SequenceOfWords` being a define it can also be a compile-time string constant if it makes it easier to solve this problem. The important thing is that this must be solved at the compile-time or preprocessing time.

Comment: As the problem is stated, you can _not_ do this at compile time using _any_ method. You can _only_ do this at runtime by making copies of the strings, splitting them into tokens, comparing individual words in each split list.

Comment: You want C++ and its `constexpr`.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of is:

Macro defining the array of pointers to strings:

```
#define LIST_OF_WORDS(...) const char *words[] = {__VA_ARGS__, NULL}
```

User can define them somewhere (in one of the compilation units available for him):

```
LIST_OF_WORDS("bar", "foo", "goo", "zoo");
```

and use the somewhere else:

```
extern *words[];

int main(void)
{
    const char **wrds = words;

    while(*wrds)
    {
        printf("WORD: `%s`\n", *wrds++);
    }
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/7qenaTxjq

Answer (score 0):

> I want to extract every word from #define ListOfWords that appears in #SequenceOfWords and create a compile-time string array of extracted words const char* extractedWords[] = {bear, black}.

It is not possible. This is (way, way!) too complicated task for C preprocessor. Preprocessor offers no string parsing functions.

Usually in C, *user* has to satisfy himself some constraint, otherwise he will get "undefined behavior". You could add a `#define ExtractedWords` where user has to himself extract the words. It's on the user to generate it correctly.

Or you could use something else than C preprocessor to parse user configuration and generate a C header file from it. Python, Bash, Perl, M4 and other languages with the help of a build system like CMake or Automake are used for that.